# How to evaluate this C# expression

Tags: c#, equation

c# simple answer needed (exam)

I have an exam tomorrow in c# and Im going over past papers. One question is as follows

If x = 3, y = 4 and z = 2, is the following statement true or false?

```
x <= y && !(z > -5 | y > 7)
```

There are no answers provided for these. Also could you go into detail(step by step) about how the answer is got.
Thanks!

I tried running it but it gives me an error?

This is my code as i tried to run it to figure it out

```
int x, y,z;
            x = 3;
            y = 4;
            z = 2;

             !(z > -5 | y > 7);

             if (x <= y)
                 Console.WriteLine("True");
             else
                 Console.WriteLine("False");
             Console.ReadLine();
```

but i get these errors:
Error   1   Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement

Comment: Why don't you run it?

Comment: If you run and debug it, you can inspect each comparison and see the results. It's a great way of learning.

Comment: I tried but it gives me an error?

Comment: Then post your code and error, so that we can help you with that.

Comment: then I would suggest posting the code and the error  but in this case the rror is quite easy to catch: | instead of ||

Comment: there's a typo in your statement: `|` is a bitwise operator, you need to use `||` for boolean or.

Comment: I'll update it hold on two mins

Comment: **I tried running it but it gives me an error**.... what's the error message?

Comment: @Herm For boolean | and || do logically the same thing, THe main difference is that || shortcuts so with `x || y` if x is true then it does not check y. The same applies to & and &&.

Comment: `|` will continue testing even tough first statement is true as for `||` will not check further conditions if one is true. `||` is very helpful when checking null and value on the same conditional branch.

Comment: the statement `!(z > -5 | y > 7);` is not valid, you need to assign the result to a variable, `var result = !(z > -5 | y > 7);` then `if (x <= y && result)`

Comment: It's unclear to me why people say that it's unclear what the user is asking. Although not the perfect question, the user's problem is quite clear... Find another reason for flagging the question!

Comment: @AndreiV Only thing that was unclear to me was what error he was talking about but as he now posted the code and the error it is quite clear now what is up there. Aside from that no clue what should have been unclear with teh question (not the best formulated one, but nobody is writing here to get a prize so whatever)

Comment: @DaveIrwin Kumars answer shows a corrected code from what I see and Ben robinsons comment shows what is wrong with your code. Does that help there?

Comment: Ya I understand it now!

Comment: @DaveIrwin In answer to the comment about upvoting you made in one of the answers: If one answer answers your question to your satisfaction then you should mark it as the answer that answered the question. an upvote is not necessary for that one then and marking it as the answer you accept  you can do regardless of your reputation

Comment: ah ok, ya I'll do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your algebra with your numbers (substitute them):

```
3 <= 4 && !(2 >-5 | 4 >7)
```

Now both sides of the && need to be true in order for the whole thing to be true.

So;

```
(3 <= 4)      is true;

 !            means 'not'/opposite of

(2 >- 5)      is true;

(4 > 7)       is false
```

So, in the end;

means

```
3 <= 4 &&      !          (2 >-5 | 4 >7)
true   AND Opposite of    (true  OR false)
```

since `true Or false` will default to '`true`':

this, overall, equates to:

```
true AND (false)
```

and so **false** is your answer

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, I completely understand it now! Again I would vote up but i don't have enough rep!

Comment: no problem, if you have any other queries feel free to ask them! As my profile says, *we all started from the bottom*

Comment: Cheeers lad will do. Ya I can't say Im very good at this stuff at the moment

Comment: @DaveIrwin: It takes time, but it will come given time (i've only been coding for just over two years now lol) So i know it wasn't long ago I was asking the same questions!

Answer (score 1):

This  x <= y  is `true`.

This `(z > -5 | y > 7)` is `true`, because one of the two conditions is true, `z > -5`

Hence this x <= y && !(z > -5 | y > 7) is `false`.

The `!` is the negation operator. So the negation of `(z > -5 | y > 7)`, which is `true`, is `false`.

Comment: Thank you! I would vote up but i don't have enough rep!

Comment: `(z > -5 | y > 7)` is `true` because `z > -5` is `true`.

Comment: No problem - it's an easy mistake to make. The timing of the downvote was unfortunate as it wasn't me - I've actually upvoted now you've fixed it.

Comment: @petelids thank you very much. Not a problem at all.